# GCC - how to compile FFMpeg with FLV1 (aka H.263), MP3 (format and codec) and FLV (container format) only?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

So I want to compile FFMpeg C libraries (as static) not in its full default glory but for my purposes only - so that it would contain:

- 2 codec formats MP3 and FLV1 (H.263)
- 2 file (container) formats MP3 and FLV

Of course I only want to limit only range of formats and codecs. Not functions of FFmpeg.

How to do such thing?

What is my main point:

To have such ffmpeg build that [when I call function like](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudClient/src/multiplexer.cpp?r=1081)

```
multiplexer::multiplexer(std::string container)
{
        av_register_all();

        this->format_context = avformat_alloc_context();
        if (this->format_context == NULL)
        {
                std::cout << "Multiplexer: format context is empty." << std::endl;
                throw internal_exception();
        }

        this->format_context->oformat = av_guess_format(container.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
        if (this->format_context->oformat == NULL)
        {
                std::cout << "Multiplexer: invalid container format (" << container << ")." << std::endl;
                throw internal_exception();
        }
}
```

I would be limited to FLV only

Comment: @Znarkus: no, I think this is ok here, SU would be for installing it for a particular Linux flavor, or getting a non-limited version for Fedora or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `configure` script has a list of options.  Run `./configure --help` to see them.  I'm not sure how options stack, but you could try `--disable-everything` followed by `--enable-demuxer=flv` etc.